# Delete unused packages from requirements file

Tags: python, pip, refactoring, pycharm, requirements.txt

Is there any easy way to delete no-more-using packages from **requirements** file?

I wrote a bash script for this task but, it doesn't work as I expected. Because, some packages are not used following their PyPI project names. For example;

```
dj-database-url
```

package is used as

```
dj_database_url
```

My project has many packages in its own requirements file, so, searching them one-by-one is too messy, error-prone and takes too much time. As I searched, IDEs don't have this property, yet.

Comment: I recently released [deptry](https://fpgmaas.github.io/deptry/), a command line utility that checks for various issues with a project's dependencies, such as obsolete, missing or transitive dependencies. It supports `requirement.txt` files since version 0.4.0.

Answer (score 138):

You can use Code Inspection in [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).

1. Delete the contents of your `requirements.txt` but keep the empty file.
2. Load your project in,
3. PyCharm go to `Code -> Inspect code...`.
4. Choose `Whole project` option in dialog and click `OK`.
   In inspection results panel locate `Package requirements` section under `Python` (note that this section will be showed only if there is any `requirements.txt` or `setup.py` file).
   The section will contain one of the following messages:

- `Package requirement '<package>' is not satisfied` if there is any package that is listed in `requirements.txt` but not used in any .py file.
- `Package '<package>' is not listed in project requirements` if there is any package that is used in .py files, but not listed in `requirements.txt`.

You are interested in the second inspection.
You can add all used packages to `requirements.txt` by right clicking the `Package requirements` section and selecting `Apply Fix 'Add requirements '<package>' to requirements.txt'`. Note that it will show only one package name, but it will actually add all used packages to `requirements.txt` if called for section.

If you want, you can add them one by one, just right click the inspection corresponding to certain package and choose `Apply Fix 'Add requirements '<package>' to requirements.txt'`, repeat for each inspection of this kind.

After that you can create clean virtual environment and install packages from new `requirements.txt`.

Also note that PyCharm has import optimisation feature, see [Optimize imports...](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/optimizing-imports.html). It can be useful to use this feature before any other steps listed above.

[image: Apply fix for all packages not listed in requirements.txt]

Comment: I followed these instructions with version 2016.2, build 162.1237.1 and it missed several of the imports. Seems like it has troubles with importing names from modules.

For example, at the top of one of my files is:  
`from rest_framework import status`
and it didn't add `rest_framework` to my requirements file using the above steps

Comment: Whilst this is a good attempt, it's not a great solution for packages whose module names differ from the package names, as @Nwilson pointed out. Also, PyCharm will not add Version numbers to the requirements, this is problematic for anyone trying to clean up a project in production.

Comment: Have any way to auto add specify version in PyCharm ?

Comment: Update for newer versions of PyCharm (works in 2020.3 Professional for me):

Instead of starting from scratch and building up a new requirements.txt, you can use the "Sync Python Requirements" tool (under the Tools menu) to find and remove unused packages (check the "Remove unused requirements" box).

Comment: This could be a nightmare if you "inspect" a project and contain the whole dependencies inside of it, so delete the dependencies (if you have a virtual env. initialized) and then follow the answer compse by @NickAb.

Answer (score 25):

You can find obsolete dependencies by using [deptry](https://fpgmaas.github.io/deptry/), a command line utility that checks for various issues with a project's dependencies, such as unused, missing or transitive dependencies.

Add it to your project with

```
pip install deptry
```

and then run

```
deptry .
```

Example output:

```
Scanning 2 files...

requirements.txt: DEP002 'pandas' defined as a dependency but not used in the codebase
Found 1 dependency issue.
```

Note that for the best results, you should be using a virtual environment for your project, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41799834/8037249).

Disclaimer: I am the author of `deptry`.

Comment: thanks for this tool @Florian, I tried it locally on one of my pet projects, works fine, but gave the following dependency error for `util` and `views` imports, which were false alarms:

---
There are dependencies missing from the project's list of dependencies:

 util
 views

Consider adding them to your project's dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @pranavcode for the feedback. For now, you can ignore those by running deptry as `deptry . -io util,views`, or adding configuration to `pyproject.toml`. Could you elaborate why they are false alarms? `util` and `views` do not seem to be part of the standard library. `deptry` should also ignore relative imports and local directories with an `__init__.py` file. Would you consider raising an issue in the GitHub repository? I'd be happy to improve `deptry` based on your feedback.

Comment: @pranavcode I was finally able to reproduce the bug you described. It's solved in release `0.6.2` by [this](https://github.com/fpgmaas/deptry/pull/163) Merge Request.

Comment: @Florian the tool would be great, but currently it has some packages marked as "The project contains obsolete dependencies", which are not. This unfortunately makes the package unusable for a real project

Comment: @HAL9000 Sorry for the late reply and thanks for your feedback. I am curious for the cause of your issue, I have not encountered that problem myself yet. As a workaround, you can configure deptry to ignore them as follows: `deptry . --ignore-obsolete "foo,bar"`

Answer (score 23):

The best bet is to use a (**fresh**) python venv/virtual-env with **no** packages, or only those you definitely know you need, test your package - installing missing packages with `pip` as you hit problems which should be quite quick for most software then use the `pip freeze` command to list the packages you really need.  Better you you could use `pip wheel` to create a wheel with the packages in.
The other approach would be to:

1. Use [pylint](http://www.pylint.org/) to check each file for unused imports and delete them, (you should be doing this anyway),
2. Run your tests to make sure that it was right,
3. Use a tool like [snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/) or [snakefood3](https://github.com/Trim21/snakefood3) to generate your new list of dependencies

Note that for any dependency checking to work well it is advisable to avoid conditional import and import within functions.

Also note that to be **sure** you have everything then it is a good idea to build a new venv/virtual-env and install from your dependencies list then re-test your code.

Comment: Thanks for answer.We also use virtual-env (the app is on the production also)This question raises during a refactoring.That's why I asked.

Comment: Note that `snakefood` does not support `python3`, and the URL to the source on the website is wrong currently, it's: https://github.com/blais/snakefood

Comment: @miyalys - thanks for flagging this up - a quick search on pypi throws up snakefood3 (https://github.com/Trim21/snakefood3) which I have yet to try as I prefer to use a bare venv as a starting point.

Answer (score 8):

In **pycharm** go to **Tools -> Sync Python Requirements**. There's a 'Remove unused requirements' checkbox.

Comment: it works like a ...charm! This is the smoothest, cleanest, fastest solution among all answers.

Comment: uhmmm does this just use the interpreter you configured to sync that with the requirements.txt file? What if the interpreter has extraneous packages?

Comment: What if the interpreter has extraneous packages? Go to File -> Settings -> Project -> Python Interpreter to remove the packages that you don't use.

Comment: does this just use the interpreter you configured to sync that with the requirements.txt file? yes

Answer (score 0):

I've used with success [pip-check-reqs](https://github.com/r1chardj0n3s/pip-check-reqs).

With command `pip-extra-reqs your_directory` it will check for all unused dependencies in `your_directory`

Install it with `pip install pip-check-reqs`.

Comment: This tool is unable to read requirements from `setup.cfg` file, which is still the most portable place to specify them in 2020 (due to lack of consensus around pyproject.toml format).

Comment: Update: Version 2.2 added `--requirements-file` and `--skip-incompatible` flag (full disclosure: I did the PRs). We use it extensively at work for around ~200 libraries and have no trouble keeping the requirements clean that way.

Comment: @sorin I might try implementing it, if you point me at a good example. Also, didn't the usage of `setup.cfg` alone [already mandate the usage of `pyproject.toml`?](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#setup-cfg-only-projects).

Comment: Using `pip-missing-reqs my_app_folder_container` could work if your project doesn't contain a complex structure | architecture. I use this package inside of a FastApi project with a "moderate size" and works pretty nice.

Comment: Update from 2022, I used pip-check-reqs. it works