# How do I add the --trusted-host in pycharm package install?

Tags: python, pycharm, package

I installed Pycharm community Edition 2016.1.4 on a Windows 7 machine and tried to update some packages used by the project I intend to work on. The update failed because the local repository "*is not trusted or a secure host*" (according to *pip*), so to update packages in the command-line I need to run:

```
pip install <package> --trusted-host <insecure-host>
```

Is it possible to specify in PyCharm that *--trusted-host* option or is Pycharm so concerned about my security that it won't allow me to do so?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After some digging I found the answer. Registering it here in case someone is interested.

Go to

> *File* --> *Settings* --> Project: *name_of_the_project* --> *Project Interpreter*

Choose (double click) the package you want to update and the *Available Packages* will pop-up. There is a checkbox *Options* on the lower-left part of the window. Check that and enter

> --trusted-host *hostname*

Option and hit the *Install Package* button.

That way I was able to update the package from the insecure host, thus solving my problem.

Comment: Is there way to install using requirments.txt file using pycharm?

Comment: @sfgroups [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376213/delete-unused-packages-from-requirements-file) might help you.

Comment: I've just answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59103592/adding-trusted-host-to-pycharm-package-installer) about the same thing, and contemplated marking it as a duplicate of this but... the OP was already entering `--trusted-host` in options but your answer doesn't explicitly state that you should enter `--trusted-host <hostname> ` - if you'd care to add that in your answer, I can flag the other one as a duplicate.

Comment: @DavidBuck just did as you asked!

Comment: Do you know of any way to permanently add a trusted host to pycharm?