# adding --trusted-host to pycharm package installer

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to add --trusted-host to Pycharm (2018.2.5 community editions) package installer. However it does not work.

for exampl: python -m pip install scipy --trusted-host pypi.org

[image]

I even tried to add "--trusted-host pypi.org " in the option. Still doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add the --trusted-host in pycharm package install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468224/how-do-i-add-the-trusted-host-in-pycharm-package-install)

Comment: no that solution does not work.

Comment: This is a very different error to your original screenshot and, unfortunately, one I haven't managed to recreate despite downgrading pip, etc. to try to match your configuration. Perhaps [upgrade pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies) and try again?

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded pip and now it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your output it shows that you are only supplying

```
--trusted-host
```

as the option and, the way PyCharm has built the command, it has tried to execute

```
pip install --trusted-host scipy
```

hence the error "You must give at least one requirement to install". This is the same error as if you had just tried to execute `pip install` with no arguments. It has interpreted `scipy` as part of the `--trusted-host` option, therefore you're not trying to install anything.

Adding

```
--trusted-host pypi.org
```

as the option works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, However I have already tried it. didn't work, I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the other hostname:
--trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org