# Creating a virtualenv with preinstalled packages as in requirements.txt

Tags: python, virtualenv

Creating a virtualenv will create a virtual python environment with preinstalled pip, setuptools and wheels.

Is there a way to specify what packages to pre-install in that virtualenv apart from those 3 default ones? Either with CLI arguments, a file, or environment variables of some sort.

I.e. is there something along the lines of `virtualenv venv && venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt` which can be run in one command?

Comment: You answered your own question. That's exactly how you would do it with that one liner

Comment: I'm wondering though if virtualenv providing those capabilities by itself.

Comment: I'm missing only one detail: how do you name the environment? I usually have one for every project.

Comment: Just answered my own question. Given:
```$ cd my_project_folder```
```$ virtualenv venv```
"venv" is the name of the environment; it can be anything. Source: _Hitchhiker's Guide to Python_, "Pipenv & Virtual Environments" "venv" is used by convention and is recommended.

Comment: @GDB In fact .venv is recommended currently.

Comment: `.env` is quite common as well (personally, I prefer it over .`venv` since it's one less character and just as obvious/canonical). So much so that it's even in GitHub's pre-made Python gitignore: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Typically the steps you always takes are:

- `git clone <repo>`
- `cd <repo>`
- `pip install virtualenv` (if you don't already have virtualenv installed)
- `virtualenv venv` to create your new environment (called 'venv' here)
- `source venv/bin/activate` to enter the virtual environment
- `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install the requirements in the current environment

Comment: I believe you also need a `python -m virtualenv env` step after installing the venv.

Comment: I only did `python -m virtualenv venv`. I didn't need to install venv.

Comment: @r03 what version of python are you using? That must mean that virtualenv is installed as a base package with python now?

Comment: I installed python 3.7.3, but maybe I had a previous installation so I might be wrong here.

Comment: `source venv/Scripts/activate` should work in later versions or you can make symlink as suggested here https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/97586.

Comment: This is great. Keep in mind that you want to create your virtual env using the same python version that the original env was created in. So if you're original env was python 3.8, you would do this with `virtualenv --python=python3.8 venv`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a tool called pipenv now!

https://www.kennethreitz.org/essays/announcing-pipenv

Just run

```
pipenv install requests
```

And it will create a virtualenv and install requests in it

Comment: I see plenty of activity at https://github.com/pypa/pipenv -- doesn't look abandoned.

Comment: I tried pipenv and I loved it...until I tried to run something in a docker container.  pipenv did not work in the docker container despite quite a bit of research and effort on my part.  You might have better skills/luck though.

Comment: https://www.kennethreitz.org/essays/announcing-pipenv is a dead link as of this comment's date

Comment: @FrostKiwi seems like there's a new URL: https://kennethreitz.org/essays/2017/01/23/announcing-pipenv but indeed, the tool does not seem to be maintained all that much anymore and you're better off using venv and pip

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`virtualenv --system-site-packages venv`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows (powershell) these are the steps you take:

1. `pip install virtualenv` to install virtualenv (if not installed already)
2. `virtualenv venv` to create your new environment
3. `venv/Scripts/activate` to enter the virtual environment
4. `pip install -r requirements.txt` to
   install the requirements in the current virtual environment