# Remove redundancy in requirements.txt in Django projects

Tags: python, django, dependencies, requirements.txt

I wonder if there is a tool by which we can figure out what **packages** are not in used in our **requirements.txt** because I have tons of dependencies written in the **requirements.txt** but I am sure a lot of them are not in use but at the same time I am not sure as well.

Looking for some help via **tools** or any **conventional method** if thats possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376213/delete-unused-packages-from-requirements-file)

Answer (score 2):

I also had tons of unused packages (until I learned how to use virtualenv properly). My requirements.txt was way too long. For me, [pipreqs](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs) helped to reduce it to the packages I really need:

1. Go to your project folder and remove the virtual environment (if existant): `rm -r venv`
2. Install pipreqs: `pip install pipreqs`
3. Run pipreqs: `pipreqs --force`
4. Install new virtual environment: `python3 -m venv venv`
5. Activate it: `source venv/bin/activate`
6. Install required modules: `pip install -r requirements.txt`
7. Build the complete list which includes the dependencies: `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Caveat: I am not an experienced programmer, I found this solution by myself and I did not check it extensively (so far), but a quick check shows that my Django project is still working.