# Cleaning up requirements.txt

Tags: python, pycharm, package

I was playing with Python and Machine Learning. During the experimental phase, I added more and more stuff to the `requirements.txt` file.

Now that I know what code I want to keep, I have deleted those experiments which are not helpful. Thus, some requirements have become obsolete. I'm now looking for a way to clean up my `requirements.txt` file.

Initially I thought I could just clear the file entirely and then go through the `import` statements and let PyCharm add them. However, that's not a good idea, because it will just add the latest version of the library, which isn't always possible. I need some libraries in special versions.

Is there a good way to clean up the requirements? I'm thinking of an action similar to "Optimize imports" (PyCharm) or "remove unused variable" or "Remove unused libraries" (Resharper).

Comment: For the record: here is a reference on _how to remove the requirements and add again all that are used in the project_. You state explicitly that this is not enough (due to specific versions) but it may be useful to other readers, for context.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376213/delete-unused-packages-from-requirements-file

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a pypi package that could be useful - [pip_check_reqs](https://pypi.org/project/pip_check_reqs/).

It looks like there is a tool in it - `pip-extra-reqs` that

> would find anything that is listed in requirements.txt but that is not
>   imported by sample.

I guess in this example "sample" is your python module:

```sh
pip-extra-reqs --ignore-file=sample/tests/* sample
```

I would give that package a try.