# Python code checker for modules included in requirements.txt but unused?

Tags: python, static-analysis, requirements.txt

Is there any automatic Python code checker that would check if a given project is present in `requirements.txt` (or `pyproject.toml`, or Pipenv's lock file) but never imported, thus unused?

Comment: Not that I know one exists, but it would be quite simple to write on your own. Make a parser read a `requirements.txt`/`pyproject.toml` and then read all `.py` files in the root, check if `import X` or `from X` is found as a string in each files content, X being each module included in the requirements. This would be slow but it's the only way I can imagine it would work.

Comment: @zeehyt Unfortunately it's not quite that simple since the name of a package on PyPI (what you put in `requirements.txt`) isn't necessarily the same as the name of the Python package(s) that package includes. E.g.,  `scikit-learn` <-> `sklearn`, `Pillow` <-> `PIL`.

Comment: @Brian Yeah I see where you're getting at, sorry I don't know either but that would be a fantastic tool

Comment: I don't that this is possible using static analysis. Many packages do dynamic imports of various grades of complexity, and so the only way to find out what is actually imported is to execute the code.

Comment: @Brian I recently tried to develop a tool that identifies unused packages, which is also able to deal with the differences in PyPi package names and the imported module names; see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73685484/8037249) if you are interested.