# How to remove unused packages installed with pip in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requirements.txt

I have Python project and have installed hundreds of packages using pip over time. However, I have since improved my code and suspect that some of these packages are no longer in use. I want to remove all of the unused packages.

I am already familiar with the `pip uninstall package-name` command and have seen suggestions to use `pip-autoremove package-name`, but it's not considered to be the optimal option for my case as there are hundreds of unused packages, and I do not want to manually uninstall each one.

Additionally, I do not want to accidentally remove packages that are still being used in my project.

I am wondering if there is a better solution, or a way to look for python imports inside files and detect for unused. Any latest or alternative approaches would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Here's my requirements.txt with thousands of packages:
[image]

Comment: thats why you should use venv and use only needed packages for the project.

Comment: did you look on this answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376213/delete-unused-packages-from-requirements-file
it looks like it solve your problem

Comment: In addition to @DumpEldor 's linked question, I also recommend having unit tests in CI running with both a minimum version constrained `pkg >= version` set of directly used packages, as well as a pinned set `pkg == version` from pip-compile/pip-freeze. This way you have a frozen set of versions to use in production while also ensuring that the latest versions of dependencies will work when you go to update the pip freeze requirements .

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well, but Package requirements section is not showing for me.

Comment: It's better to look at it from the other direction: find the packages that you _do_ need to run your app/project. Create a venv with _no_ packages installed. Run, importerror, install missing packages, run again, importerror, ... repeat until you have all the packages. Then `pip freeze` your new requirements.txt. Much _much_ better if you already have tests you can just keep running. Similar to the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42237193/2745495

Answer (score 0):

Dependency management in Python is a painful topic. Check out this excellent overview: https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2023/01/15/how-to-improve-python-packaging/

I highly recommend you check out Poetry or Hatch for dependency and packaging management. In general you should at least always use virtual environment. This allows you to completely delete it and create new, if you need.

You have your requirements.txt so you can do
`python -m venv <venv>` where `<venv>` is the name you want to give to your virtual environment. It creates a directory where you will install the packages. Activating the virtual environment goes like this: `source <venv>/bin/activate` which executes a shell script. Among other things it defines a command `deactivate` which you can call if you wish to exit from the virtual environment. With the activated `venv` everything you install will be installed there.